# SlidingTabLayout inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am facing problem with `SlidingTabLayout`. I want to have a `ViewPager` inside of `Fragment` (Fragment is placed inside other Fragment), and it works just fine as long as I am using `PagerTabStrip`. I wanted to change it to `SlidingTabLayout`, but then there are some NullPointerException. I've copied SlidingTabLayout.java and SlidingTabStrip.java from Google's iosched app.

Adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private static int NUM_ITEMS = 2;
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NUM_ITEMS;
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new BlankFragment();
        case 1:
            return new BlankFragment();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Tab One";
        case 1:
            return "Tab Two";
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

and in onCreateView is this:

```
 mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this.getFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    new setAdapterTask().execute();
    mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    mTabs.setViewPager(mViewPager);
```

I just wonder why all the logic works fine for `PagerTabStrip` but not for `SlidingTabLayout`. NullPointerException appears in SlidingTabLayout.java in `populateTabStrip()`, to be more precise on `adapter.getCount()` instruction. Could anyone help me fix this?

EDIT
NullPointerException comes from this in SlidingTabLayout.java in `populateTabStrip()`, because adapter is null. Why does it not notice my adapter?

```
final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter(); // <-it is always null
```